# Multiple Python versions in the same Ubuntu machine

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am on an Ubuntu machine, where Python 3.10 is automatically installed. To do a given task in a shared codebase I need to use Python 3.9 for some issues with new versions.

I would like to have both of the Python installed on my machine and be able to use both and switching if I need to.

So, I am trying to install old Python 3.9 with the command `sudo apt-get install python3.9` and it succeeded in installation, but I can't find it anywhere even with `which python3.9` and similar.

Even the python interpreter option in VSCode does not show it.

I think I am missing something. Can please someone help me? Thank you

Comment: `which` doesn't always work. Try `type` instead. If that doesn't help, what repo did you install it from? You can confirm by running `apt policy python3.9`. I assume you used deadsnakes (`http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu`).

Comment: You're running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Jammy), right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python should be installed under the `/usr/bin/` folder. If it's not there, you might have not actually installed the package.

Check out [this guide](https://www.makeuseof.com/install-python-ubuntu/) for installing specific versions (Scroll down to the "Use Deadsnakes PPA to Install Python 3 on Ubuntu" section.)

This will allow you to install specific version of python like `python3.9`

Answer (score 0):

Packages on Ubuntu (usually executables) are installed in the `/usr/bin` directory. You could try to list all executables under `/usr/bin` with

```
ls /usr/bin/python*
```

This is the easiest way. You could see also what packages are installed

```
apt list --installed | grep python
```